# GetManifest() and GetThumbnail() fail on some Item Version of Forge Model Derivative API

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I'm using Forge c# client library to read A360 hub/project/folders structure using a 3legged token (Model Derivative API).

For every [Version]  of a [Item] in [Data Service] of A360 i need to know:

1. if a file has conversion errors;
2. if it has a thumbnail, get it;
3. if a item version is ready show it in the viewer (using viewer v.
   2.xx)....

After authentication, i correctly see the users account hub-project-folders structure:

> A360Hub
>
> ---Samples
>
> ------Golden Bridge Gate.dwf
>
> ---------Golden Bridge Gate.dwf (v1)
>
> ------V8 Engine.iam
>
> ---------V8 Engine.iam (v1)

When i call the GetManifest()  using [Golden Bridge Gate.dwf (v1)] urn i get the expected result:

```
string strGoldenBridgeGateV1_urn (v1) urn1 = "dXJuOmFk......_dmVyc2lvbj0x";

....
DerivativesApi.GetManifest(strGoldenBridgeGateV1_urn)->OK
DerivativesApi.GetThumbnail(strGoldenBridgeGateV1_urn)->OK
....
```

When i call the same code using [V8 Engine.iam (v1)] urn i get "Error 404: not found".

```
....
string strV8EngineIamV1_urn="dXJuOmFkc2su........Gc_dmVyc2lvbj0x";
DerivativesApi.GetManifest(strV8EngineIamV1_urn)->FAIL (404)
DerivativesApi.GetThumbnail(strV8EngineIamV1_urn)->Fail (404)
....

Error details:
-------------- Exception:

Error code:404

HResult:-2146233088

Stack:

Autodesk.Forge.Client.ApiException: Error calling GetThumbnail:     in
Autodesk.Forge.DerivativesApi.GetThumbnailWithHttpInfo(String urn,
Nullable`1 width, Nullable`1 height)    in
Autodesk.Forge.DerivativesApi.GetThumbnail(String urn, Nullable`1
width, Nullable`1 height)    in my code...
```

Same happens on file with other files:  it works with .RVT,.DWF files;
it fails with .IAM, .NWC, .SLDASM, .IFC files....

Any idea?

Comment: please express your question clearly, "Any idea?" is too broad. Do you want to know source of the problem, solution? Also, specifying right tags for question will get you help faster.

Answer (score 0):

For A360 files the translation is already there, you don't need to use Derivative API, unless you need to convert to a different format (RVT -> IFC, for instance).

**Update**: Data Management API was released in mid-2016 and old files on old accounts, specially those sample files, need to be recreated for it to work. Workaround (for sample files) is to download and upload again to a different folder. Customer data was migrated.

Take a [look at this sample](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample), is shows the viewable if available ([check this line too](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-sample/blob/master/data.management-csharp-sample/Controllers/DataManagementTreeController.cs#L237)).

[image: A360 & BIM 360 files on Data Management API]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but to get a preview of viewables I still need to use the Autodesk.Forge.DerivativesApi.GetThumbnail (String urn, width, height) method..
Moreover, the Forge Viewer (v.2.13) returns an error code 5 passing the URN of the file [V8 Engine.iam(v1)], and works well with the other...
All files are displayed correctly in the A360.

Comment: I suspecting those errors are connected, a file on A360 should have that information available on the Version level. Did you try the same I mentioned? Same error? Is it live somewhere? You can also post a private question through forge.help[at]autodesk[dot]com

Comment: The problem was due to the fact the files were uploaded in 2015 and not reconverted by Autodesk. Downloading locally and re-uploading them in a different A360 folder solved all.

Comment: thanks for updating @DiegoDiego, I have updated the answer with that. If ok, please also go ahead and mark as "Solved" here too. thanks.